# Image upload with resize using StdImageField in django getting TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

While I was uploading image with specific dimension in django rest-framework am getting the error TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'size'. I have installed stdimage app and have added in settings too.
Please help me where am wrong. Thanks in advance.
where my code is below :

```
from django.db import models
from stdimage import StdImageField
import datetime
from others.locale.models import MasterCity

class MasterBank(models.Model):
    """
    """   
    bankid            = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True,blank=True)
    bankname          = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    bankdescription   = models.TextField(blank=True)
    banklogourl       = StdImageField(upload_to = 'images/',blank=True,size=(50,50))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using size as parameters I used below code :
StdImageField(upload_to = 'images/',variations={'thumbnail': (50, 50)})

**init**.py should consist of below code :

from **future** import (absolute_import, unicode_literals)

from .models import StdImageField

and install below packages :

1. apt-get install libjpeg-dev # It is used as jpeg image decoder which was mandatory when we are using stdImage package
2. pip install -I pillow

For more detail for image upload with resizing check with this link :
https://github.com/xarg/django-stdimage